# Queryset of model instances based on related model

Tags: django, django-models

I've got two models.

```
class Color(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True) 

class Car(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Color, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

How can I get a queryset of Color instances where the Car instances that are related to those Color instances have a price > 1000?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
related_colors = Color.objects.filter(car_set__price__gt=1000)
```

Comment: Just tested this and its actually Color.objects.filter(car__price__gt=1000)

Comment: Well `car_set` is a default related query name (for reverse relation) and if you change it to something else it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant `color` instead of `user`? You can filter it as follows:

```
cars = models.Car.objects.filter(price__gte = 1000).values_list('color', flat = True)
```